# Basics of DataContractAttribute

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I'm looking at Microsoft's How to: [Create a Basic Data Contract for a Class or Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811.aspx), but it leaves me with lots of questions.

They provide this very simplistic example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
  // This member is serialized.
  [DataMember]
  internal string FullName;

  // This is serialized even though it is private.
  [DataMember]
  private int Age;

  // This is not serialized because the DataMemberAttribute 
  // has not been applied.
  private string MailingAddress;

  // This is not serialized, but the property is.
  private string telephoneNumberValue;

  [DataMember]
  public string TelephoneNumber
  {
    get { return telephoneNumberValue; }
    set { telephoneNumberValue = value; }
  }
}
```

For my case, I need this to also include another custom class object called `ADUser` (Active Directory User).

I understand that `ADUser` has to be marked with the `DataContractAttribute`, but I do not understand how exactly to go about that.

Here is Microsoft's class again, but this time with the `ADUser` field added:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
  // This member is serialized.
  [DataMember]
  internal string FullName;

  // This is serialized even though it is private.
  [DataMember]
  private int Age;

  // This is not serialized because the DataMemberAttribute 
  // has not been applied.
  private string MailingAddress;

  // This is not serialized, but the property is.
  private string telephoneNumberValue;

  [DataMember]
  public string TelephoneNumber
  {
    get { return telephoneNumberValue; }
    set { telephoneNumberValue = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public ADUser UserInfo { get; set; }

}
```

I don't really understand how or what all needs to be done to my `ADUser` class, but I feel certain that `private` stuff can be left untouched.

How would I need to **fix** this `ADUser` class example?

```
public class ADUser
{

  private string first, last, loginID;

  public ADUser() {
    first = null;
    last = null;
    loginID = null;
  }

  private void getInfo() {
    // code goes here
    // which sets loginID;
  }

  public void SetName(string first, string last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    getInfo();
  }

  public string LoginID { get { return loginID; } }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to just put `DataMember` to each field in `AdUser` and mark `ADUser` with `DataContract`?

Comment: as @outcoldman said, just need to do the same for ADUser. basically, every DataMember in DataContact needs to be serialiseable, means, if there is a class, it needs to be a DataContact as weel. also, need to make sure the class has a constructor which does not require parameters

Comment: It's that simple? OK! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@outcoldman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937252/basics-of-datacontractattribute#comment22706759_15937252) and [@EthanLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937252/basics-of-datacontractattribute#comment22709489_15937252) suggested:

1. Add the `[DataContract]` attribute to the `ADUser` class.
2. Add a *public* constructor *without* arguments.
3. Choose the fields you want to pass through WCF. Mark all of them with the `[DataMember]` attribute.
4. Properties *with only getters* will fail during serialization: all exposed properties should have *both a getter and (public!) setter*.  So, for example, your `LoginID` property will fail if you'll try to apply the `[DataMember]` attribute to it. In this case, consider changing it to be the method.

Comment: Some things that Microsoft auto creates have `[ServiceContract]` with `[OperationContract]` members and a corresponding `[DataContract]` that goes along with them. If my `ADUser` is not going to be a service, do I need to include any of that, too?

Comment: [ServiceContract] is your service, [OperationContract] - your methods

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. Step #2 is unnecessary. In step #4 (not really a step, but whatever) neither the getter nor setter need be `public`. When using `DataContractSerializer` (as WCF does), accessibility is ignored (`public` vs `private`), and the serializer does not use any constructor when deserializing, so it doesn't matter whether a parameterless one is present or not. Note that this is different from other serializers, e.g. `XmlSerializer`.